# Renorming a Banach space to make projections contractive

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $P$ be a projection in $B(X)$. Then $X$ can be renormed so that $P$ has norm $1$.

Can the same be done for a family of projections? That is, given finitely many projections $P_1$,...,$P_n$ in $B(X)$ is there an equivalent norm under which all projections become contractive?

Are there any assumptions other than $P_i$ commuting that would ensure this?

Comment: The necessary and sufficient condition is that the semigroup generated by the projections be uniformly bounded. As Andreas pointed out, this need not be true even in the plane.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let $X$ be the Euclidean plane, and consider the two projections
$$
P_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&A\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad
P_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\A&1\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $A$ is a big constant (actually any $A>1$ will do).  If a norm on $X$ gave both of them norms $\leq1$, then the same would be true for their product, and for powers of their product,which have the form
$$
(P_1P_2)^n=\begin{pmatrix}A^{2n}&A^{2n-1}\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
But these powers send the vector $\binom10$ to larger and larger vectors, which cannot all be in any ball.